# yahoo stores api authentication

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm attempting to get order data from a Yahoo store.  I'm using the docs found here: http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/vw/order-payment-api.pdf
I can't seem to get past authentication.  I've got the store id.  The store owner has turned on access for me and I've gotten the secret code to add to my xml POST request.

Anyone had any luck doing this?  If you have can you help me.

Comment: The API seems quite unreliable: at the moment, I get only 1 out of 5 requests working on average, either from DNS failure, or most of the time an error 401 for no valid reason (given the exact same request will work some minutes later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like magic this started working last weekend.  Why?  Nobody really knows.  I did send yahoo an e-mail complaining but didn't get a response.

Also, while running POSTs I found that preceding your request XML with a space is a bad idea.